# Is it bad to chown /media/USERNAME for your web server?

Tags: chown

I've been trying to get this software working for my webserver. It's called `ownCloud`. I had partitioned my hard drive just to host my files on my web server.

I made a new partition (128gb) and I've been trying to get it to work with ownCloud. But it will not work whatever I do.

It says this:

```
Data directory (/media/user/2CF254B6F254864C/ownCloud/data) is invalid

Please check that the data directory contains a file ".ocdata" in its root.
Cannot create "data" directory (/media/user/2CF254B6F254864C/ownCloud/data)

This can usually be fixed by giving the webserver write access to the root directory.
```

Even though I have that all there.

So, someone on their forum told me to use
`chown -R www-data:www-data /media/user/2CF254B6F254864C/ownCloud/data`, so I did.

But it didn't work. So then I kept going down the directories, chown'ing them.

I have www-data access to `/media/user/` Is this a bad thing? I remember I had to reinstall because I accidentally chmod'ed root with 777.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Why can't you just mount the partition to a better directory, like /var/foobar or /mnt/data? This should be possible with an entry in fstab? See here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Comment: It doesn't show up in my fdisk list, and it's not compatible, it says.

`WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   625142447   312571223+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.`

Comment: What does `ls -ld /media/user/2CF254B6F254864C/ownCloud/data/.ocdata` say?

Comment: `-rw------- 1 user user 0 Sep  7 04:17 /media/user/2CF254B6F254864C/ownCloud/data/.ocdata`

The ownCloud forum told me to do `chown -R www-data:www-data /media/user/2CF254B6F254864C/ownCloud/data/.ocdata` to get it working, giving rights to www-data, but it has never worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you think that the root problem lies with the owner of the mountpoint then in the mount options you can specify `uid` and `gid` to set the user and group respectively for the mount.  Read the manual page, `man mount`, for the specification of those options.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem

```
Data directory (...) is invalid  Please check that the data directory contains a file ".ocdata" in its root.
```

when i try to transfer my data folder from a partition to other one, and i  change the permissions of .ocdata and did not work.

My solution was change the owner (not recursive) to mount's point partition and all work well:

```
$ chown www-data:www-data /mount_point
```

---

Hola
Tuve el mismo problema

```
Data directory (...) is invalid  Please check that the data directory contains a file ".ocdata" in its root.
```

Cuando traté de transferir mi carpeta de datos de una partición a otra, y cambié los permisos de .ocdata pero no funcionó.

Mi solución fue cambiar el propietario (no recursivo) al punto de montaje de la partición nueva y todo funcionó bien:

```
$ chown www-data:www-data /mount_point
```